# Library construct, struct("string"/anythingElse) issue

Tags: python, parsing, construct

Construct is a parsing library to parse hex datas. After reading the data, you first have to define the map and then parse it. You can find an example below;

```
....
data, addr = self.s.recvfrom(1024)

c = Struct("sync"/Int16ul, "ID"/Float32l)

x = c.parse(data)

print(x.sync)
print(x.ID)
```

My problem here is I'am reading the data types, for our example Int16ul and Float32l from a list named "varBytes" programatically and their type is "str" as expected. Data names "sync" and "ID" is also in a list named "varNames".
Below is what I have tried;

```
c = Struct(varNames[0]/varBytes[0],varNames[1]/varBytes[1])
```

This is not working. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`varBytes[0]` is a string where as what you need is the `Int16ul` object from the `construct` module.

You need to turn the string into the object you can do this getting the object by its name with `getattr` applied to the module `construct`:

```
varNames[0]/getattr(construct, varBytes[0])
```

So your example becomes:

```
import construct
from construct import Struct

c = Struct(varNames[0]/getattr(construct, varBytes[0]),
           varNames[1]/getattr(construct, varBytes[1]))
```

To build the argument list from the pair of lists, one can apply `Struct` to a list:

```
c = Struct(*[varName/getattr(construct, varByte) 
             for varName, varByte in zip(varNames, varBytes)])
```

This uses `zip` as using indexes makes for index errors.

Comment: One more question Dan, how would you fill inside of Struct in a for loop? I mean, do not writing (varNames[0]/getattr(construct, varBytes[0],..,varNames[100]/getattr(construct, varBytes[100]), but using a loop to do that.